# Codes can only pass the second compilation when using \refstepcouter for cross-referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

In the following example, I try to obtain the value of the counter`bbb` in advance(before `bbb` is given a value) by `cross-referencing`, and store the value into a macro(`\aaa`) for later use. I compile the code as the steps below:

Step (1) First, Delete all temparory files(.aux,.fls,.log in this example) related to the main tex file which contains the codes below.

Step (2) Then Compile the main tex file with `xelatex`, and fails. Error messages are:

```
ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.5 \setcounter{bbb}{\ref{pp}}
```

Step (3) Then Comile the main tex file once more and succeed to get the typeset expected.

I repeat the step (1)(2)(3) several times and each try has the same result -- First compilation fails and second compilation succeeds.

I know compilation twice may be required under some conditions, but it should be two successful compilation, not like this case -- first try fails and second try succeeds.

How to make my codes pass compliation at the first time without error?

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{bbb}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{bbb}{\ref{pp}}
\edef\aaa{\thebbb}
\rule{1in}{\aaa pt}


\setcounter{bbb}{5}
\refstepcounter{bbb}\label{pp}

\end{document}
```

It seems that `\setcounter{bbb}{\ref{pp}}` is the cause. `\ref{pp}` gives `6\hbox{}`, not `6`. So this question may conver to how to seperate a number from `\hbox{}`. Any idea about it?

Comment: See the refcount or the zref package.

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike Fischer  I wonder if there is solution in the scope of pure `TeX/LaTex` to this plain requestion.

Comment: Sure. Look into refcount and imitate its code.

Comment: `\ref{pp}`  produces the print form of the pp counter so typically not a number, and it does not work by expansion, in particular if gives a warning if the ref is not yet defined

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer for me the implementation of refcount is hard to understand. Would you please provide an anwer to solve the problem of my codes?